# Cassandra Trigger unintentionally clears values from column

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-kafka

So my table has 4 columns and inserting works normal.
But as soon as i connect my Javatrigger to the table, the table does not store values in the last column anymore.

The Java Trigger itself just sets up a kafka producer, i write data to.
This shouldnt touch the table itself in any way, so i dont understand why values are being cleared.

The table still executes my insert commands but leaves the last column for "value" empty as soon as the trigger is attached.

My code for the cassandra trigger looks like the following

```
    public class JavaTrigger implements ITrigger{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JavaTrigger.class);

    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition)
    {
        String tableName = partition.metadata().cfName;
        logger.info("Table: " + tableName);

        String topicname = null;
        String type = null;
        String subtype = null;
        String id = "0";
        int value = 0;

        ByteBuffer partitionKeyValues = partition.partitionKey().getKey();

        id = new String (partitionKeyValues.array());

        try {
            UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Unfiltered un = it.next();
                Clustering clt = (Clustering) un.clustering();  
                Iterator<Cell> cells = partition.getRow(clt).cells().iterator();
                Iterator<ColumnDefinition> columns = partition.getRow(clt).columns().iterator();

                int count = 0;

                while(columns.hasNext()){
                    Cell cell = cells.next();


                    if(count == 0) {
                         String data = new String(cell.value().array()); 

                        subtype = data;
                    }

                    if(count == 1) {
                         String data = new String(cell.value().array());

                        type = data;
                    }

                    if(count == 2) {
                         int data = new Integer(cell.value().getInt()); 

                        value = data;
                    }

                    count++;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


        createAvroProducer("topic1", id, type, subtype, value);
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }


   public void createAvroProducer(String topicname, String id, String type, String subtype, int value)
    {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.2.113:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
              io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.2.113:8081");
    KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);

        String key = "key1";
        String userSchema = 
                "{\"type\":\"record\"," + "\"name\":\"myrecord\","
                + "\"namespace\" : \"MyFlink.FlinkWrapper\"," 
                + "\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"transactionid\",\"type\":\"string\"},"
                + "{\"name\":\"transactionsubtype\",\"type\":\"string\"},"
                + "{\"name\":\"transactiontype\",\"type\":\"string\"},"
                + "{\"name\":\"transactionvalue\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}";
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema schema = parser.parse(userSchema);
    GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
    avroRecord.put("transactionid", id);
    avroRecord.put("transactiontype", type);
    avroRecord.put("transactionsubtype", subtype);
    avroRecord.put("transactionvalue", value);

    ProducerRecord<Object, Object> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topicname, key, avroRecord);

      producer.send(record);
      producer.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Did you check the system.log for error ? and print the exception in the catch block

Comment: I cant see any error in the log. 
The code also executes perfectly since the kafka topic does have all 4 values. It just somehow drops the "value" entry from the cassandra column. But the Kafka topic does infact receive the correct "value" from the insert, but the table doesnt.

Comment: So i did solve my own problem.
The cell.value().getInt() method was at fault, it did return the correct value i wanted, so the producer wrote the correct entry to kafka, but apparently set my table value to null after doing so, since it is based on a relative offset.